# iPod manager to use under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ipod

What is the most reliable iPod-managing software that exists for Ubuntu 12.04?

What is the most user-friendly iPod-managing software that exists for Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using http://banshee.fm/ It has ipod/iphone support for most Android phones as well and podcast support as well as Amazons MP3 store to buy music from. The only issue is that because it's Apple you will not be able to properly synch your music , If you are using a modern iOS then the iPod uses a proprietary database format that Banshee can't access. They do actually get copied over, it's just that iTunes won't see them. Your really only option is duel booting into windows or mac.